# call_command makemigrations does not work on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a scenario, where I need to create a table dynamically, To create the table dynamically I have written code to create a model.py file with the table content that I want to create.

Once this file get created then I want to perform the makemigrations command from the code itself like

```
 from django.core.management import call_command
 call_command('makemigrations')
 call_command('migrate')
```

it is working fine in my local as well in AWS EC2 instance, but it is not working into the Elastic Beanstalk (eb). and when I'm trying to run the makemigrations command manually from the eb ssh then it gives me the following error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/python/bundle/47/app/quotations/migrations/0036_dynamic_table.py'
```

Anyone have any idea how can I handle this situation.

One Other thing is that as I'm creating new dynamic models So how can I push that code to the git, as on new deployment EBS will replace the existing code to new code, so in this way I will lose the files that I created in EBS using these commands

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Eddie that you need to modify the permissions of the migrations folder.

The migrations folder is located at: 
`/opt/python/current/app/quotations/migrations/`

You probably need to do something like:

```
subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '+w', '/opt/python/current/app/quotations/migrations/'])
```

You'll probably need this before and/or after the makemigrations call.

Please comment if you have further issues.

Comment: it's giving me this error : Operation not permitted :-(

Comment: I can see why that error would show up.
The problem is that you're trying to use Django in a way that it's not intended to be used. Can you give me an idea about why you need to create the model files dynamically?

Comment: I've written code to accomplish a feature where table fields are not specific, fields would be added by the admin dynamically, So I need to perform makemigrations and migrate command to create those table that admin want to create from admin.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple permissions error and may not have to do with EBS itself.  Do an `ls -al /opt/python/bundle/47/app/quotations/migrations/` and look to see if `0036_dynamic_table.py` already exists.  If so, delete it, if not, look at the permissions along that path to verify that the user that the migration runs-as has permissions to write and execute all the directories.

Now that I think of it, its most likely that you are not running the migration commands as the same user that owns the directory structure.  Take a look.

Comment: I am talking here to generate dynamic models, Once these models files created then I'm calling call_command('makemigrations') method
, but this command does not have sufficient permission to perform this, So I'm unable to generate migration from code only.

Comment: Right, you will need permissions to write the migrations file.  I doubt if there is going to be a way around that.